# How can I put Date Mapping in Elasticsearch 5.4 using Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, mapping, kibana-5

**Elasticsearch version 5.4.1, Kibana 5.4.1**
Date Mapping not reflected in Kibana after putting Date Mapping through **Java API**

`client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping(indexName).
            setType(type).setSource(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().
                      startObject().
                        startObject(type)
                        .startObject("properties")
                        .startObject(attributeFieldKeyValue.getAttributeValues())
                            .field("type", attributeFieldKeyValue.getDataType())
                            .field(attributeFieldKeyValue.getFieldName(), attributeFieldKeyValue.getFieldValue())
                        .endObject()
                  .endObject()
              .endObject()
              .endObject()).execute().actionGet();te().actionGet();`

Answer (score 0):

please take your time to write up more details. Are you trying to change an existing field to a date field? If so, that does not work - if you want to do that you need to reindex.

Have you checked the response if there is an error message? Did an exception occur? How did the mapping look before you executed the request.

Comment: I am applying mapping on new index. Actually my problem get resolved there is insertion time delay between elasticsearch returning ID and record actually inserted. Its because of                                                
Near Realtime (NRT) 
Elasticsearch is a near real time search platform. What this means is there is a slight latency (normally one second) from the time you index a document until the time it becomes searchable.

Comment: Thanks for your help